# How to write a cosine theorem using Java?

Tags: java, math

How to write this theorem correctly as is written in the formula?

```
package com.company;

public class Exercise8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double AB = 6;
        double AC = 16;
        double Angle = 60;
        double CosOfAngle = 0.5;
        // Почему-то значение косинуса 60 градусов вместо 0.5, пишет
        // -0.9524129804151563 ?  ?  ? (Do not  pay  attention)
        // Formula is  BC^2 = AB^2 + AC^2 - 2AB*AC * cos A
        double bc = (2 * (Math.pow(AB, 2) + Math.pow(AC, 2) - ((AB * AC))) * CosOfAngle);
        double BC = Math.sqrt(bc);
        double P = AB + BC + AC;
        double p = 0.5 * P; // Где p - полупериметр
        double S0 = (p * ((p - AB) * (p - BC) * (p - AC)));
        double S1 = Math.sqrt(S0);
        double S = Math.round(S1);

        System.out.println("Perimeter of triangle is : " + P + " cm ");
        System.out.println("Area of triangle is : " + S + " cm^2 ");
    }

}
```

Comment: This question is poorly asked, and is either unclear or too broad. Read [ask] to see how to write a good question. Asking for debugging/homework service is not a valid question.

Comment: Yeah, thank`s I realized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in this line:

`double bc = (2 * (Math.pow(AB, 2) + Math.pow(AC, 2) - ((AB * AC))) * CosOfAngle);`

which should be:

`double bc = Math.pow(AB, 2) + Math.pow(AC, 2) - 2 * AB * AC * CosOfAngle;`

You were multiplying the whole formula by 2, whereas only the cosine part needs to be multiplied by two. There were too many confusing parenthesis. Removing them made it a lot clearer.

Comment: Using AB*AB to square values seems better than Math.pow() to me.

Comment: @duffymo That's true, but I generally prefer to copy the original syntax to make it easier to point out the real mistake instead of inserting optimizations in the process. But I agree that you answer is the real way of coding it. Take my upvote!

Comment: Thank you very much! It`s very helpful advice

Comment: @duffymo While your approach is surely better, I interpreted the OP's question as asking _"Where have I gone wrong?"_ rather than looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This seems simple to me:

```
// https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-cosine-law.html
public double lawOfCosines(double a, double b, double angleInRadians) {
    return Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b - 2.0*a*b*Math.cos(angleInRadians)); 
}
```